# How to listen to mouse events on canvas in Draw2D library?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, draw2d-js

I want to allow the user to draw a rectangle on the canvas with [Draw2D](http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d/index.html) library. The canvas location of mouse-down will be top-left and the canvas location of mouse-up should become the bottom right. However, I am unable to catch the mouse-up and mouse-down events on the canvas.

Here is the code I am trying, but there is no output:

```
var canvas = new draw2d.Canvas("canvas-div");
var policy = new draw2d.policy.canvas.CanvasPolicy();
policy.onClick = function(canvas, mouseX, mouseY) {
    console.log("Mouse click:" + mouseX + "," + mouseY);
}
canvas.installEditPolicy(policy);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Draw2D-js you need always to extend Classes if you want to do something new.
(*you are redefining method with the wrong way*)

in your exemple you can create this:

```
  var MyPolicy = draw2d.policy.canvas.CanvasPolicy.extend({
  NAME: 'MyPolicy',
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    alert("done");
  },
  onClick: function(the, mouseX, mouseY, shiftKey, ctrlKey) {
    this._super(the, mouseX, mouseY, shiftKey, ctrlKey);
    alert("MyPolicy click:" + mouseX + "," + mouseY);
  }
 });
```

and than use it like this:

```
var policy = new MyPolicy();
canvas.installEditPolicy(policy);
```

another method is to use JQuery directly:

```
$('#draw2Did').click(function(ev) { 
      alert("Mouse click:" + ev.clientX + "," +ev.clientY); }
);
```

Reference:

> http://draw2d.org/draw2d_touch/jsdoc_5/#!/api/draw2d.policy.canvas.CanvasPolicy